# How to merge (join) data frames based on string matching?

Tags: r, string, merge, tidyverse, character

TL;DR: I want to merge two dataframes based on a column that contains multiple synonyms of an identifier.

This is my first ever question to stackoverflow but I have been stuck with this seemingly simple problem for far too long so I would be very grateful for any help!

I have two dataframes that both contain one or multiple character columns describing a row. I would like to merge these dataframes, and although sometimes they have a direct match, there is no single identifier column but rather multiple synonyms that could match.

Here is a simple reproducible example for the two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame("Name" = c("a", "b", "c"))
df2 <- data.frame("Symbol" = c("a", "two", "d"), 
                  "Synonym" = c("", "b | 2", "c-four"))
```

I would like the first row to match directly ("a"), the second row to match the synonym ("b") and the third row to not match ("c"). (The non-matched row ("d") may or may not be included in the output.)

Here is the dataframe I would like as an output of the merge:

```
goal_df <- data.frame("Name" = c("a", "b", "c", NA),
                      "Symbol" = c("a", "two", NA, "d"),
                      "Synonym" = c("", "b | 2", NA, "c-four"))
```

[screenshot of goal dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKWbt.png)

In pseudo-code, this is what I would like to do:

1. create a new column in df1 called 'match' that will contain information on whether or not there is a match between df1 and df2 for any given row in df1
2. compare df1$Name and df2$Symbol and populate df1$match with df2$Symbol if they are identical
3. if they are not identical, look for an exact match in the df2$Synonym column, if it is found, assign the corresponding df2$Symbol to df1$match
4. merge the two dataframes based on df1$match and df2$Symbol

Here is (some of the things) I've tried so far:

First, I split the synonyms into individual strings for each synonym to allow exact comparison (This creates a list type because there can be multiple synonyms per row):

```
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(syns = strsplit(df2$Synonym, split = "|", fixed = T))
```

```
df3 <- df1 %>% mutate(
  match = case_when(
    Name %in% df2$Symbol ~ Name,
    Name %in% df2$syns ~ df2$Symbol, #this line
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
left_join(df2, by = c("match" = "Symbol"), all.x = T)
```

Unfortunately, *this line* won't compute correctly for multiple reasons, I guess.

Alternatives I've tried for *this line* :

```
sapply(Name, grep, df2$syns) ~ df2$Symbol, #this line

sapply(paste0("\\b", Name, "\\b"), grep, df2$syns) ~ df2$Symbol, #this line
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `match = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! LHS of case 2 (`sapply(Name, grep, df2$syns)`) must be
  a logical vector, not a list.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Maybe it is the wrong approach to strsplit the Synonym column first? I'm not sure 1) how to match only exact matches (so that it doesn't match "c" and "c-four" for example) and 2) how to merge the two dataframes once I have compared the strings successfully (because it doesn't seem to be possible to assign a value from a different dataframe in case_when).

I hope I described my question thoroughly! Thanks in advance for any help you can offer. I feel hilariously stuck at this seemingly simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this using `fuzzyjoin`:

(`%>%` may also be used instead of `|>`.)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 <- data.frame("Name" = c("a", "b", "c"))
df2 <- data.frame("Symbol" = c("a", "two", "d"), 
                  "Synonym" = c("", "b | 2", "c-four"))

df2_regex <- df2 |> 
  mutate(regex = str_c(Symbol, Synonym, sep = "|") |> 
           str_remove_all(" ") |> 
           str_remove("\\|$") |> 
           str_replace_all("\\|", "$\\|^"),
         regex = str_c("^", regex, "$")
  )

df1 |> 
  regex_full_join(df2_regex, by = c(Name = "regex")) |> 
  select(-regex)
#>   Name Symbol Synonym
#> 1    a      a        
#> 2    b    two   b | 2
#> 3    c   <NA>    <NA>
#> 4 <NA>      d  c-four
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot @Carl! This definitely joined the two tables. It is also working perfectly as intended for my example case. However, when I apply it to my actual case (with a lot more data), there is some let's say 'overmatching' taking place. My df1$Name of "ATP5L" matched several Synonyms:
[1] "ATP5|ATP5A|ATP5J|ATPM|CF6|F6"                               
[2] "ATP5JG|ATP5L"                                               
[3] "CEMCOX1|ECGF1|Gliostatin|MYP6|PD-ECGF|SCO1L|TP|TYMP|TdRPase"
[4] "AGAT|AT|CCDS3|FRTS1"   
The corresponding Symbols:
[1] "ATP5PF" [2] "ATP5MG" [3] "SCO2"  [4] "GATM"

Comment: Obviously, I would only want [2] to be a hit. I tried to dig a bit into how regex_join works and it seems like it uses stringr::str_detect which claims it is working equivalent to grepl. However, when I run grepl (like so: which(grepl("ATP5L", df2_regex$regex))), I only get the correct hit. Do you have an idea why this may be the case? Thank you so much already!

Comment: Okay, ha, I think the problem is that it does the grepl the other way around, thus [1] "ATP5" [2] "ATP5L" [3] "TP" and [4] "AT" all create a hit with "ATP5L". Do you know if there is a way to reverse the way the regex is operated @Carl?

Comment: See if this helps. I've tweaked the regex to wrap each piece with `^` and `$` to get exact matches.